# how do I do port forwarding on WBR-3407a?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I am attempting to establish a connection between two computers using MSDN codes:

Client code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737591(v=vs.85).aspx

Server code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737593(v=vs.85).aspx

These codes run perfectly on a local network, but my intention is to establish a connection over the internet, where both computers are behind routers. I know port-forwarding is a viable solution. But I just don't know how.

I am unable to properly configure my router to port-forward. Its model is Level One WBR-3407a. I tried this guide: http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/LevelOne/WBR-3407a/defaultguide.htm But it didn't work. As you may note, this guide doesn't anywhere in it specify what port to use? is it possible to port-forward without specifying which port to forward?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This router only allows you to forward ports that are predefined.

Looks ancient anyway. Get a new one.

Comment: Predefined by the manufacturer? So there are ones that I can already use?

Comment: Yes. That's what your guide says. Classics like 80 (aka "Web"), for example.

Comment: The guide doesn't mention any. How to know them?

Comment: They're in the last screenshot. But seriously, get a new router. They're cheap and way more powerful these days.

Comment: @kalkanistovinko    WEB,POP3,SMTP    are TCP-  80,110,25.     FTP is 21 but possibly not just 21 maybe 22 too.   DNS is UDP 53 (maybe can be TCP 53 not sure).    So in short, it looks like you def have ports TCP 80,110,25,21  available to you to choose to do port forwarding on.  It should work whatever is running on those ports.  so you could run a whatever server on port 80 doesn't have to be a web server.